# mBean - how to enable and disable calling method

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I'm writing application with mBeans. I can call their methods using jConsole.

Do you have any idea how to disable/enable calling method from mBean? For example I'd like to permit calling method when some condition is fulfilled.

I have an application with timer. I have a class that has a timer (that count from 0 to 100 in loop), the class has also mBean (registers and uses it). I'd like to allow call methods on mBean (from jConsole) only if timer is between 0-50 and forbid when timer is between 51-100

Comment: Do you mean not allowing anyone to call bean operation except few with privilege?

Comment: I have an application with timer. I have a class that has a timer (that count from 0 to 100 in loop), the class has also mBean (registers and uses it). I'd like to allow call methods on mBean (from jConsole) only if timer is between 0-50 and forbid when timer is between 51-100.

Comment: Probably I didn't follow completely but when the operation is called on the MBean, could you check the timer value and return if its between 51-100? I am assuming its more complicated than this but the question is not very clear.